# How do I make a while loop that will keep taking string input until i input nothing?

Tags: c

I'm working in C and I want to make a loop that will make my code keep asking for input until I input ""?

```
char inputarray[1000];
int size;
printf("\nEnter a string: ");
fgets(inputarray,1000,stdin);  
size = strlen(inputarray);
printf("%d \n", size);
printf("%s \n", inputarray);
```

Comment: Also I'm new to stack overflow and don't know how to make a new line when inputting code. Will be glad to hear any solutions

Comment: You might want to check out about ***memcmp*** or ***strcmp*** functions

Comment: And you might want to clear out what the exit condition is

Comment: Just as a side note: You should normally always check the return value of `fgets` to see if an end-of-file or error condition occurred. For example, if standard input has been redirected to come from a file, then it is likely for an end-of-file condition to occur. However, this is not related to your problem, so you can ignore this advice for now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char inputarray[1000];
  int size;

  do
  {
    printf("\nEnter a string: ");
    if(!fgets(inputarray,1000,stdin)) /* Check for EOF , or NULL upon return */
    {
      return -1;
    }
    size = strlen(inputarray)-1; /* Ignoring '\n' */
    printf("%d \n", size);
    printf("%s ", inputarray); /* No need for '\n' since 
                                fgets stores every character including newline in the buffer */

  }while(strcmp(inputarray,"\n")); /* Meaning strcmp doesnt return 0 */

  return 0;
}
```